# Unexpected ellipsis in syslog or splunk message

Tags: log4j, syslog, splunk

I am logging data to Splunk via log4j and a SyslogAppender.  Sometimes the information shows up in Splunk with ellipsis (...) instead of the actual text with some odd spacing.  When I log the same event to a RollingFileAppender, it logs normally.  Would anyone know why this is happening and how to resolve it?
Thank you!

Example:
InboundTxnDate: 20130926 16:53:14:475
Out...
...boundTxnTypeCode: UNK

Answer (score 1):

This is how syslog appenders work, they split log message, if it is bigger than 1019 bytes. When log message is split, this message will end with ellipsis and next message starts with ellipsis. Limit of message (1019 bytes) is hardcoded and cannot be changed by no configuration in log4j. Look at [RFC 3164](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3164.txt) and see source code of [SyslogAppender](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.15/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.java#SyslogAppender.splitPacket%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29>)

Answer (score 0):

> Would anyone know why this is happening

[Ondřej Benkovský answered that very well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200970/399105) and I have nothing to add.

> how to resolve it?

If the split lines are part of the same event in Splunk, you can join them by editing `$SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/props.conf` and adding a stanza like this:

```
[<spec>]
SEDCMD-join_log4j_syslog_lines=s/\.\.\.[\r\n]+\.\.\.//g
```

That will join the lines at index time and remove the ellipses.

Note that you'll need to change `<spec>` as detailed in the document for [props.conf](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/propsconf).

You can use the [regex search command](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Regex) to make sure it's working:

```
 | regex "\.\.\.[\r\n]+\.\.\."
```